# if method_one returns value return value, else try method_two in ruby

Tags: ruby

How do I say if `method_one` returns a value, then break, else try `method_two`?

```
def ai_second_move(board)
  p "2nd move called"
  # TODO - how to say if method_one gives me a value, break, else method_two
  method_one(board)
  method_two(board) 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using if -

```
method_two(board) if method_one(board).nil?
```

using unless -

```
method_two(board) unless !method_one(board).nil?
```

using ternary -

```
# This evaluates if (method_one(board) returns nil) condition. If its true then next statement is method_two(board) else return is executed next.
method_one(board).nil? ? method_two(board) : return
```

Comment: I think you got it bakckwards. The requirement is to execute `method_two` iff `method_one` yields `nil`.

Comment: Thank you, I used the unless version.

Comment: you're welcome, though I'd use `if` in such situation. With `unless` you end up using double negation which sometimes can be tricky to follow.

Answer (score 7):

Most Ruby way of writing this would be:

```
method_one(board) || method_two(board)
```

Ruby executes the right-hand side of `||` only if the left hand side evaluated to false (meaning it returns `nil` or `false`) and then the result of this expression would be that of the `method_two`

Comment: and yes this one works as well...I choose the answer by Ashish only because it will read better to me when I'm looking at the code 3 months from now :)

Comment: You're welcome - code maintainability is (should) be top priority for most projects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `return`. `break` is for loops.

```
def ai_second_move(board)
  p "2nd move called"
  return if !!method_one(board)

  method_two(board) 
end
```

An other fun way would be

```
def ai_second_move(board)
  p "2nd move called"
  !!method_one(board) || method_two(board) 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work as well:

```
method_one(board) and return
```

The `return` statement is executed only if `method_one(board)` returns a truthy value.